# What response status code is returned when a YouTube playlist is full?

Tags: youtube-api

To save me having to fill a playlist with 200 videos, could someone tell me if a specific response status code is returned when trying to add a video to a playlist already containing 200 videos?

I want to avoid checking the size of a playlist each time before adding a video.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a playlist with 200 videos and attempting to add another, the response status was '400 Bad request', along with a body of XML with an internal reason "Playlist too big".

Comment: Weird—I guess something changed in the past few years.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you'll get back a `403 Forbidden` in that scenario, with the response body containing an XML document detailing the reason for the error.

If you happen to be using the Java GData client library, it will be deserialized as a `ServiceForbiddenException`, as you can see from [this code](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct/source/browse/trunk/ytd/src/com/google/ytd/youtube/YouTubeApiHelper.java#479).